# "Missing dependencies" of ngx-bootstrap library

Tags: angular, npm, ngx-bootstrap

After updating Angular from version 7 to 11, gradually, I am getting an error when I try to start the application. I tried 3x starting all over again, but still the same result. Any clue or idea would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: Are you following the angular update guide? https://update.angular.io/

Comment: @pixelbits Yes, I've done those same exact steps.

Comment: Sometimes when you're updating you have to ignore the errors (run update with the force flag), and continue on. Just make sure that ngx-bootstrap is compatible with the version that you're upgrading to. Most of the issues when upgrading is because of incompatible libraries. So you might need to pin the versions of those libraries to a specific version. Your focus should be upgrading the core Ng libs (other libs can remain at lower versions and upgraded at a later time)

Comment: @pixelbits I did that, adding at the end of npm command "--allow-dirty --force", version of Angular is 11 and of the ngx-bootstrap is 3.3.0

Comment: Check this dependency chart for ngx-bootstrap: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-bootstrap#compatibility. Version 3.3.0 is not compatible with angular 11

Comment: I've missed that, compiling successfully some parts ngx-bootstrap got me confused, thanks anyway

Comment: You should upgrade ngx-bootstrap to version 7.  Version 7 supports Angular 11: https://github.com/valor-software/ngx-bootstrap/blob/v7.0.0-rc.1/package.json

Comment: I've done that, but still need to update other ngx dependencies to see if the end result will be successful